# wordpress wp-admin/includes/shema.php file has been modify alone

Tags: wp-admin, core

I have a problem, a file from wp-admin has been modified alone or after deactivated/activated my own plugin .
I never modified any files inside wp-admin, I don't know why now.
I am currently creating a plugin to add some information inside database from a form .
After updating a table inside database, i must deactivated and activated the plugin to apply the changes.
Also I have to get a backup of one file inside wp-content from my host ! I can't imagine that this process was able to modify a file of wp-admin

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ')' in website/wp-admin/includes/schema.php on line 440

after checking, the content of the file is deleted after line 440: "'ping_sites' =>

Does anyone have any idea why.

Comment: Most likely it was an automatic update that failed to complete. The solution to that is to perform a manual update: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update I doubt deactivating and reactivating the plugin had anything to do with it. Likely a coincidence.

Comment: I copied / pasted the original shema.php file and the issue was resolved.
@Jacob Peattie, I would like it to be that, but i haven't done manual / automatic wordpress core updates for a week. 
Something has done this or my host probably has an error in a script while restoring a backup, but the wp-admin folder is not supposed to be affected.

I worked on my plugin without problem before the error appeared while updating a table in my database.

This I would like to know, can it become a vulnerability?
Should I question my host?
thanks

Comment: You could ask your host. I still recommend doing a manual update, you don’t know what other files might be affected.

Comment: thanks, I will do that. I suppose there are no others files affected. I don't have other errors .

Comment: Just because you don’t see any errors now doesn’t mean there aren’t issues. Please just do the update.